# What's up with custom flags for migrations

Tags: support, migration, custom-flags

From question [Cleaner solution to decrementing in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172052/cleaner-solution-to-decrementing-in-for-loop)

I tried to post a custom flag recommending migration to codereview.stackexchange.com where it seems better fit and got a very long automatic flag response about rejected migrations being frustrating to the OP (which is true) and first verify the question is well-written (which it is) but the flag won't go through at all.

> Think this question should be migrated to another site? Please first check that it is clearly-written and on-topic for the site you're recommending. If you aren't an experienced member of that site, please take some time to read their help center first; rejected migrations are frustrating to both askers and the good people on the site who must reject it. Thanks!

So yeah I double check but I cannot post the flag. I do not get it.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag? What was the text you entered?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: "Any chance of a migration to codereview.stackexchange.com?"

Comment: Seems like the word "migration" triggers that warning. I tested with "This question might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com" and it went through.

Comment: I also tested it with 'This is clean and well written, but this question may be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com'. yeah it seems like they have a regex check for the word migration for some reason?